# keep data in form when clicking submit

Tags: php, form-submit

EDIT: Apologies - all code now pasted below

Apologies for the first time newbie question - I've been looking for an answer here and on google - I get the feeling this is some simple coding i'm messing up. 
I've created a form which, when you validate, you check all the data on the same page and the original data is kept in the original form so you can make changes if you wish.
I have a section of the form where this doesn't work however - where you can ask multiple questions and each question can have up to 4 answers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<head>
<title>Test page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylenewtest.css" type="text/css" />
<script language="javascript" src="tableadd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$string = isset($_POST['quiz_format']) ? $_POST['quiz_format'] : false;
$quiz_format = ereg_replace("[^0-9a-zA-Z?ąćęłńóśżźĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŻŹ\. ]", "", $string);
$stringquiz_100 = isset($_POST['quiz_100']) ? $_POST['quiz_100'] : false;
$quiz_100 = ereg_replace("[^0-9a-zA-Z?ąćęłńóśżźĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŻŹ\. ]", "", $stringquiz_100);
$stringquiz_fback = isset($_POST['quiz_fback']) ? $_POST['quiz_fback'] : false;
$quiz_fback = ereg_replace("[^0-9a-zA-Z?ąćęłńóśżźĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŻŹ\. ]", "", $stringquiz_fback);
$stringquiz_title = isset($_POST['quiz_title']) ? $_POST['quiz_title'] : false;
$quiz_title = ereg_replace("[^0-9a-zA-Z?ąćęłńóśżźĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŻŹ\. ]", "", $stringquiz_title);
$stringquiz_instruct = isset($_POST['quiz_instruct']) ? $_POST['quiz_instruct'] : false;
$quiz_instruct = ereg_replace("[^0-9a-zA-Z?ąćęłńóśżźĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŻŹ\?,\"\'\._@\\/ !&()=\+;:\t\r\n-]", "", $stringquiz_instruct);
$stringquiz_time = isset($_POST['quiz_time']) ? $_POST['quiz_time'] : false;
$quiz_time = ereg_replace("[^0-9a-zA-Z?ąćęłńóśżźĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŻŹ\. ]", "", $stringquiz_time);
?>
<div id="content">
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action=""> 
<div class="datagrid">
<table>
<tr><th colspan="2">Please choose the format of the quiz<span class="error">*</span></th></tr>
<tr><td>Hangman</td><td><input type="radio" name="quiz_format" <?php if (isset($quiz_format) && $quiz_format=="Hangman") echo "checked";?> value="Hangman"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Gap fill</td><td><input type="radio" name="quiz_format" <?php if (isset($quiz_format) && $quiz_format=="Gap fill") echo "checked";?> value="Gap fill"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Multiple choice</td><td><input type="radio" name="quiz_format" <?php if (isset($quiz_format) && $quiz_format=="Multiple Choice") echo "checked";?> value="Multiple choice"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Simple Q & A</td><td><input type="radio" name="quiz_format" <?php if (isset($quiz_format) && $quiz_format=="Simple Q & A") echo "checked";?> value="Simple Q & A"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Word formation hangman</td><td><input type="radio" name="quiz_format" <?php if (isset($quiz_format) && $quiz_format=="Word formation hangman") echo "checked";?> value="Word formation hangman"></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<br />
<div class="datagrid">
<table>
<tr><th colspan="2">Continue repeating the exercise until 100% achieved?<span class="error">*</span></th></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td><td><input type="radio" name="quiz_100" <?php if (isset($quiz_100) && $quiz_100=="Yes") echo "checked";?> value="Yes"></td></tr>
<tr><td>No</td><td><input type="radio" name="quiz_100" <?php if (isset($quiz_100) && $quiz_100=="No") echo "checked";?> value="No"></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<br />
<div class="datagrid">
<table>
<tr><th colspan="2">Show the answer as correct/incorrect after every question or just at the end?<span class="error">*</span></th></tr>
<tr><td>After every question</td><td><input type="radio" name="quiz_fback" <?php if (isset($quiz_fback) && $quiz_fback=="After every question") echo "checked";?> value="After every question"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Just at the end</td><td><input type="radio" name="quiz_fback" <?php if (isset($quiz_fback) && $quiz_fback=="Just at the end") echo "checked";?> value="Just at the end"></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<br />
<div class="datagrid">
<table>
<tr><th colspan="2">Please enter in the title of the quiz<span class="error">*</span></th></tr>
<tr><td>Quiz title:</td><td><input type="text" name="quiz_title" value="<?php echo $_POST[quiz_title];?>"></td></tr>
</table>
<br />
<table>
<tr><th colspan="2">Please enter in the instructions for the quiz<span class="error">*</span></th></tr>
<tr><td>Quiz instructions:</td><td><textarea name="quiz_instruct" rows="10" cols="40"><?php echo $_POST[quiz_instruct];?></textarea></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<br />
<div class="datagrid">
<script language="javascript">
window.onload = moreFields;
window.onload = init;
</script>
<table>
<tr><th colspan="5">Please enter in the quiz's questions and answers:<span class="error">*</span></th></tr>
</table>
<div id="readroot" style="display: none">
<input type="button" value="Remove a question field"
    onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" />
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Question:</td>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="q[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['q'][$i] ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Answer 1:</td>
    <td>Answer 2:</td>
    <td>Answer 3:</td>
    <td>Answer 4:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="a1[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['a1'][$i] ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="a2[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['a2'][$i] ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="a3[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['a3'][$i] ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="a4[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['a4'][$i] ?>"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<span id="writeroot"></span><input type="button" id="moreFields" value="Click here to add further question fields" /><br />
</div>
<br />
<div class="datagrid">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
</table> 
</div>
</form>

<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['Submit1'] ) ) { 
echo "<form method=post action=insert.php>";
echo "<h1>Please confirm the quiz details are correct</h1>";
echo "<div class=datagrid>";
echo "<table>";
if(empty($string)){
echo("<tr><td>Quiz format:</td><td><h3>Please go back and choose a quiz format<h3></td></tr>");
$showbutton=1;
}
else{
echo("<tr><td>Quiz format:</td><td>" . $quiz_format . "</td></tr>");
echo("<input type=hidden name=quiz_format value='" . $quiz_format . "' />");
}
if(empty($stringquiz_100)){
echo("<tr><td>Continue repeating the exercise until a 100% score is achieved?:</td><td><h3>Please go back and choose an option<h3></td></tr>");
$showbutton=1;
}
else{
echo("<tr><td>Continue repeating the exercise until a 100% score is achieved?:</td><td>" . $quiz_100 . "</td></tr>");
echo("<input type=hidden name=quiz_100 value='" . $quiz_100 . "' />");
}
if(empty($stringquiz_100)){
echo("<tr><td>Do you want the answer to be shown after every question or at the end of the quiz?:</td><td><h3>Please go back and choose an option<h3></td></tr>");
$showbutton=1;
}
else{
echo("<tr><td>Do you want the answer to be shown after every question or at the end of the quiz?:</td><td>" . $quiz_fback . "</td></tr>");
echo("<input type=hidden name=quiz_fback value='" . $quiz_fback . "' />");
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<div class=datagrid>";
echo "<table>";
if(empty($stringquiz_title)){
echo("<tr><td>Quiz title:</td><td><h3>Please go back and enter in a title for the quiz</h3></td></tr>");
$showbutton=1;
}
else{
echo("<tr><td>Quiz title:</td><td>" . $quiz_title . "</td></tr>");
echo("<input type=hidden name=quiz_title value='" . $quiz_title . "' />");
}
if(empty($stringquiz_instruct)){
echo("<tr><td>Quiz instructions:</td><td><h3>Please go back and enter in instructions for the quiz</h3></td></tr>");
$showbutton=1;
}
else{
echo("<tr><td>Quiz instructions:</td><td>" . $quiz_instruct . "</td></tr>");
echo("<input type=hidden name=quiz_instruct value='" . $quiz_instruct . "' />");
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<div class=datagrid>";
echo "<table>";
if(empty($stringquiz_time)){
echo("<tr><td>Time limit:</td><td>not specified</td></tr>");
}
else
{
echo("<tr><td>Time limit:</td><td>" . $quiz_time . "</td></tr>");
echo("<input type=hidden name=quiz_time value='" . $quiz_time . "' />");
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<div class=datagrid>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td colspan=5>The questions and answers to your quiz:</td></tr>";
$aq = $_POST['q'];
$aa1 = $_POST['a1'];
$aa2 = $_POST['a2'];
$aa3 = $_POST['a3'];
$aa4 = $_POST['a4'];
$N = count($aq);
for($i=1; $i < $N; $i++){
if($aq[$i]==""){
echo("<tr><td>Question:</td><td><h3>Please go back and enter a question</h3></td></tr>");
$showbutton=1;
}
elseif($aa1[$i]==""){
echo("<tr><td>Answer:</td><td><h3>Please go back and enter at least one answer</h3></td></tr>");
$showbutton=1;
}
else{
 echo ("<table><tr><td>Question:</td><td colspan=3>" . $aq[$i]. "<input type=hidden name=q[] value='" . $aq[$i] . "'></td></tr>
<tr><td>Answer 1:</td><td>Answer 2:</td><td>Answer 3:</td><td>Answer 4:</td></tr>
<tr><td>" .$aa1[$i] . " <input type=hidden name=a1[] value='" .$aa1[$i] . "'></td>
<td>" .$aa2[$i] . " <input type=hidden name=a2[] value='" .$aa2[$i] . "'></td>
<td>" .$aa3[$i] . " <input type=hidden name=a3[] value='" .$aa3[$i] . "'></td>
<td>" .$aa4[$i] . " <input type=hidden name=a4[] value='" .$aa4[$i] . "'></td> </tr></table>");
  }
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<div class=datagrid>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td><input type=button value='<< Go Back' onclick='goBack()' /></td></tr>";
if ($showbutton =="1"){
}
else{
echo "<tr><td><input type=submit value=Submit></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
}
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but every time I submit, the questions and answers carry through but the form fields lose all the data. How can I keep the data in the fields?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: How is $a1, $a2 etc getting the values? Show us that code.

Comment: I'm having problems with what you said about: ***"where you can ask multiple questions and each question can have up to 4 answers."***. I have working code that I can post, but that part about the "multiple questions" is where I'm stumped. You only have the 1 question and multiple answers posted as code. I need to know how the multiple "questions" come into play.

Comment: $aq = $_POST['q'];
$aa1 = $_POST['a1'];
$aa2 = $_POST['a2'];
$aa3 = $_POST['a3'];
$aa4 = $_POST['a4'];
$N = count($aq);
 for($i=1; $i < $N; $i++){
 echo ("<table><tr><td>Question:</td><td colspan=3>" . $aq[$i]. "<input type=hidden name=q[] value='" . $aq[$i] . "'></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Answer 1:</td><td>Answer 2:</td><td>Answer 3:</td><td>Answer 4:</td></tr><tr><td>" .$aa1[$i] . " <input type=hidden name=a1[] value='" .$aa1[$i] . "'></td></tr></table>");}}

Comment: apologies for the code - tried to paste hopefully what was after. The multiple questions refer the the js script which controls the table - <script language="javascript">
window.onload = moreFields;
window.onload = init;
</script> onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that JS was involved and to be honest, JS is not my strong point. You need to put all that code in your question and not in comments, in order for others who will visit your question, know what they have to deal with exactly. Also add the "javascript" tag. @user3162674

Comment: sorry - code now updated in OP

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the value of the input to either `$_POST['old_value_name]` or `$_GET['old_value_name']` depending on which form method you are using.  Therefore, your new code would look something like this (assuming that you are looking for the key $i from your question):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Question:</td>
        <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="q[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['q'][$i] ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Answer 1:</td>
        <td>Answer 2:</td>
        <td>Answer 3:</td>
        <td>Answer 4:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="a1[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['a1'][$i] ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="a2[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['a2'][$i] ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="a3[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['a3'][$i] ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="a4[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['a3'][$i] ?>"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense. The name is _a1[]_ which will create an array of _a1_ in the $_POST . So if you need to refer to that you do it **$_POST['a1'][key]**

Comment: Hello All,Thanks for your help - the data is still not being kept in the fields though. I think it's probably my fault for not giving enough information. This table functions with a js script - not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: If you are using a javascript method similar to: <form name="myform" action="handle-data.php">
Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
<a href="javascript: submitform()">Search</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>, using `$_GET` seemed to work perfectly well.

Comment: <script language="javascript">
window.onload = moreFields;
window.onload = init;
</script> <input type="button" value="Remove a question field"
  onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" />

Comment: Just tried with <php echo $_GET['a1'][$i] ?> - no joy i'm afraid

Comment: I do not see the code for where the form is actually submitted.  Could you post the entire code?  However, javascript is not my strong point, so I will try to help to the best of my ability.

Comment: Sorry, but I still see no method for submitting the form.  This is how the code appears: http://prntscr.com/2gqsan  In order to get the user input, there needs to be some button / other method for them to submit it.

Comment: sorry - it's a standard submit button:<table>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
</table>

Comment: I think I see the problem.  You need to wrap the inputs and submit button in `<form method="post" action=""></form>`.  Without the `<form>`, the submit button does nothing and you receive no user input from `$_POST[]`.  Also, action was simply left blank to reload the current page to submit the data.  If you would like it to redirect to another page, you could use `action="redirect_here.php"`.

Comment: I wanted to avoid reloading to another page as the data kept on being lost and I was told that putting everything on one page is the way forward - however, now I've learnt a thing or two about how php works I might go back to the two page approach. will try your suggestion re: wrapping

Comment: It didn't work - have now uploaded the whole script - it isn't data intelligence work after all. I'm grateful if you have any ideas.

Comment: Two comments: (1) `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is not needed.  Just use `action=""` to accomplish the same goal.  The second part of this comment is only if you want to continue using `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` or if you want to know why it did not work the first time.  (2) You echoed a htmlspecialchars() link which makes it into an invalid link for action.  Action must be in one of the following forms: `action="http://domain.com/gohere.php"`, `action="/gohere.php"`, `action="//domain.com/gohere.php"`, or `action="gohere.php"`.

Comment: I was working from the template from w3schools (told you I was newbie :) ). Does this mean it should just read: form method="post" action=""> to get it working?

Comment: Yes but don't forget `<` before form: `<form method="post" action="">`

Comment: Sorry to be a total numbnuts on this - but I replaced the code and it still doesn't work

Comment: Be more descriptive.  What didn't work?  Did it not submit the variables or were you not able to retrieve the variables?  You can use `<?php print_r(get_defined_vars()) ?>` to check for what variables were submitted.

Comment: Sorry - I replaced the code and tested using 2 questions (i.e. added one more question field). When I clicked submit, the text was pasted on to the 'confirm if the data is ok part' but it was wiped from the html table part and the Q&A fields reset back to one Q&A field

Comment: <?php print_r(get_defined_vars()) ?> comes back with a whole load of data - anything particular you want to know?

Comment: I just reviewed the code and the problem is you are using variables before even defining them.  For example, you use `$quiz_format` for whether the input box is checked.  However, it will never be set since you define it far after using it.

Comment: It's not an issue for anything other than the question and answer fields - the radio buttons, other text fields (quiz_title) and comments fields (quiz_instruct) all behave in the way that they should i.e. keep the answer which was chosen and display in the lower 'check if it's correct' part. It must be sth with the coding with that particular part. I know the coding isn't brilliant - most of it is a hatchet job of one kind or another, but it's only the Q&A , as mentioned, that's causing difficulty unless I'm totally missing/not understanding sth (more than likely)

Comment: That would be very odd unless there is code ahead of what was posted.  As far as I can see, `$quiz_title` and `$quiz_instruct` are not defined until after the inputs as well, which would cause the code not to work.  You can try testing it by putting `$quiz_title = 'Test quiz title';` at the top of the code.  If it works for the value of the text input, it means that you do not define it before using it for the value of the input.  If it does not work, there is something wrong with the code itself.

Comment: you're right - it works for the value of the text input. OK, given the fact I'm completely clueless, could I ask you to provide me with one example of what it should look like so I could extrapolate the rest from it?

Comment: for example, you could move both `$stringquiz_title = isset($_POST['quiz_title']) ? $_POST['quiz_title'] : false;` and `$quiz_title = ereg_replace("[^0-9a-zA-Z?&#261;&#263;&#281;&#322;&#324;ó&#347;&#380;&#378;&#260;&#262;&#280;&#321;&#323;Ó&#346;&#379;&#377;\. ]", "", $stringquiz_title);` to the top of the code and just do the same for the `$quiz_instruct` variable.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help - have made all changes as suggested and now all fields remember what they're supposed to .... except the bloody q&a fields. Guess I'm not going to win on this one. Will update the code in the original OP.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood your problem you want to keep values in a form after they were sent to server.
 
  "I've created a form which, when you validate, you check all the data on the same page and the original data is kept in the original form so you can make changes if you wish"

It's ok. I remember I wanted the same a few months ago. This is why I tried to help.

There is only a problem that after pressing "submit" button form is sent to server and page is reloaded.
In return you get a new page from webserver which you pointed in the form field "action".

I would do it so:

```
    Target form: <br/>
    <form id="target" action="index.php" method='post'>
        <input  name="first_field" type="text" value="<?php  if ( isset($_POST['first_field']) ) 
            echo  $_POST['first_field'];     ?>"  /> <br/>
        <input name="second_field" type="text" value="<?php if (  isset($_POST['second_field'])) 
       echo $_POST['second_field'];?>" /> <br/>            

         <p><b>What kind of girls do you like?:</b><Br>
            <input type="radio" name="browser" value="brunette" <?php if( $_POST['browser']==="brunette" ) echo "checked";  ?>  >  brunette<Br>
            <input type="radio" name="browser" value="blonde" <?php if( $_POST['browser']==="blonde" ) echo "checked";  ?>  > blonde<Br>
            <input type="radio" name="browser" value="red" <?php if( $_POST['browser']==="red" ) echo "checked";  ?> > red<Br>
         </p>


        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Any ideas how it can be changed/improved  are encouraged.